# C# How to add a hyphen before each uppercase character in a string

Tags: c#, string, uppercase

How do I find the uppercase letters of an existing string and add (-) before each of them?

```
string inputStr = "fhkSGJndjHkjsdA";
string outputStr = String.Concat(inputStr.Where(x => Char.IsUpper(x)));
Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This code finds the uppercase letters and prints them on the screen, but I want it to print:
`fhk-S-G-Jndj-Hkjsd-A`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Ahmad. Please take the [tour]. This also might be helpful :  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `string outputStr = String.Concat(inputStr.Select(x => Char.IsUpper(x) ? "-" + x : x));` or something along those lines (since I suspect I am not handling strings and chars correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I think that using a RegEx would be much easier:

```cs
string outputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "([A-Z])", "-$1");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this took care of my problem. I'm new to c # :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using Linq's aggregate:

```
string inputStr = "fhkSGJndjHkjsdA";
var result = inputStr.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (acc, symbol) =>
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(symbol))
        {
            acc.Append('-');
            acc.Append(symbol);
        }
        else
        {
            acc.Append(symbol);
        }
        return acc;
    }).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) *Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate* and then `String.Concat` will concatenate all the values giving you *SGJHA*.

Instead, you could use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0), check per character for an uppercase char and return the char prepended with a `-` or the same char as a string when not an uppercase char.

```
string inputStr = "fhkSGJndjHkjsdA";
String outputStr = String.Concat(inputStr.Select(c => Char.IsUpper(c) ? "-" + c : c.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
```

Output

```
fhk-S-G-Jndj-Hkjsd-A
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/xyZbaK)

---

To also find unicode uppercase characters using a regex, you could use `\p{Lu}` to find an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant as [Char.IsUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=net-5.0) checks for a Unicode character.

In the replacement, you can use the full match using `$0` prepended with a `-`

```
string inputStr = "fhkSGJndjHkjsdA";
string outputStr = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"\p{Lu}", "-$0");
Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
```

Output

```
fhk-S-G-Jndj-Hkjsd-A
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/j95gZV)